# How to get ARNs of older AWS Lambda runtime versions used prior to January 24, 2023?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Some of my AWS Lambda functions started crashing around January 2023, although I did not publish an update in the meantime. The chances are high that it is caused by an update of the managed runtime.

I would like to revert the runtime used on those specific functions to a prior version that is known to work.
The possibility to handle runtime versions on AWS Lambda is very new at the time of writing. Log files now show a line indicating the ARN of the runtime used.

For instance, in my case: `arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1::runtime:be4a32da6aeaa90583d476cb548ced79ae2c9aa7b14a45129198bbd13ea5822d`

The new configuration options allow to force the use of a specific runtime version instead of the latest. Which would solve my problem, at least temporarily. There is no list to select from; the exact ARN has to be provided instead.

But it is not possible AFAIK to guess the ARNs of runtime versions used before January 24, 2023. How can I get those?

For the technical details, this is a NodeJS 14 environment, and the function uses C++ dependencies built using node-gyp. The newly-introduced crash is due to `GLIBCXX_3.4.29` not found in the native code.

Comment: A support ticket is your best bet, unless you happen to have older logs; it doesn't look like there's an API to retrieve this info. Moving forward, you can lock the runtime by versioning your Lambdas.

Comment: I still have old logs; they do not have the line with the version. The logging of the runtime version ARN is part of the new features.